# Having trouble with a simple loop when trying to print two numbers to the screen at once

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to make ask the user for how many numbers of the Fibonacci sequence displayed to the screen. I have everything done pretty much, but since i am printing two numbers to the screen at a time, it is printing double of what the user enters. I would just divide the number the user enters by two, but the wont work for odd numbers. If anyone can think of a solution for this, thank you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number <-- the fibonacci number if you dont know it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "How many numbers do you want generated in the Fibonacci sequence.\n";

    int num;
    cin >> num;

    int num1 = 0, num2 = 1;
    int sum;
    int f = 1;

    while (f <= num)
    {
        cout << num1 << setw(5) << num2 << setw(5);
        sum = num1 + num2;
        num1 = sum;
        num2 = sum + num2;
        ++f;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about just `f+=2` instead of `++f`?

Comment: i tried that but that will always print in pairs so no odd number would work

Comment: Well you need to change `f = 1` to `f = 0` and `f <= num` to `f < num` too. `f` should track the count that you've already printed.

Comment: thanks for the help but someone else answered it

Comment: Pay attention to the advice I gave you: track the count of what you've printed and start at `0`, because that more closely matches what you're trying to accomplish. You'll have fewer problems in the future.

Comment: i did what you said but it still isnt printing the right amount of numbers.

Comment: what cash cow said worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop something like:

```
while ( f <= num )
{
    cout << num1 << setw(5);
    if ( ++f <= num )
    {
        cout << num2 << setw(5);

    /// rest of calcs
       ++f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're generating two numbers at a time, you need to increment your counter 2 at a time:

```
int f = 0;
for (; f < num; f += 2) {
    // body
}
```

And then if `num` is even, print the last one

```
if (f == num) {
    // print num1
}
```

Comment: Each loop is generating 2 fib numbers.

Comment: that doesnt work. That leaves out half of the numbers i need to print

Comment: @CashCow Got confused by what "printing double" meant.

Answer (score 0):

In a Fibonacci series, you need a minimun of 2, anything less has no meaning. More than 2 you just have to print the sum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "How many numbers do you want generated in the Fibonacci sequence.\n";

    int num;
    cin >> num;

    int num1 = 0, num2 = 1;
    int sum;
    cout << num1 << setw(5) << num2 << setw(5);
    int f = 3;

    while (f <= num)
    {
        sum = num1 + num2;
        cout << sum << setw(5);
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = sum;
        ++f;
    }
    cout << std::endl;
}
```